# Configuring a centralized entity

Tags: ef-core-3.0

I have a very centralized table "RecordInfo" which holds some general data 
e.g.: UserModified, UserCreated, DateTimeCreated, etc.

This table should be accessible via a navigation property from any other table in my application. Therefore I'm using a GUID Column to join the tables.

So it acts similar an one-to-one relation, but I cannot make a Foreign Key to multiple target tables. This will not work due to the FK constraints.

So I'm searching for a solution to implement navigation properties, without defining a ForeignKey - is this possible in any way?

Comment: Why do you want that? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve with this? I can thing of several serious issues this will cause but no benefits. Never mind the GUIDs, which are always a bad choice even when you use a sequential algorithm to generate them.

Comment: An abstract base class may be just fine (simple properties are fine too), and a global filter can set those values without the entities themselves knowing anything about them. Adding such a centralized *table* would cause havoc with the database schema. Without foreign keys you'd have no idea whether that table contains valid data or not. Using it would require JOINs and incur the cost you tried to avoid by removing FKs

Comment: The proper solution depends on what you want to do. If you want to keep track of changes, SQL Server 2016's temporal tables can keep track of all changes and return data at a specific point in time. Change Tracking, available since 2005, can return the PKs for all modified rows (inserted, updated *and* deleted).

Comment: Finally, you can use [global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) or [command interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.dbcommandinterceptor.nonqueryexecuting?view=efcore-3.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Diagnostics_DbCommandInterceptor_NonQueryExecuting_System_Data_Common_DbCommand_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Diagnostics_CommandEventData_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Diagnostics_InterceptionResult_System_Int32__)  to write to a `Records` table without affecting the entities at all

Comment: It is not only a kind of change tracking what I want to do. Mainly some user /employee assignments and responsibilities should be maintained in the attached Table. It might not be an perfect solution when working with such an centralized table, but adding those columns to every single table (via inheritance), does not give me the possibility to collect all the data i need, without iteratoing through all the tables.

Comment: I tried to get around with simple properties, which seems to work good in the most of the parts I worked on